# Error when using 'import' and Node.js 8.9.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, web3js

I'm trying to get a simple node project off the ground but have run into issues using the import keyword.

I'm attempting to import a few functions from some modules from the 0x.js and @0xproject/connect packages but when I try to run my main.js I get the following error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as Web3 from 'web3';
                                                          ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

When I pull down the project from https://github.com/0xProject/connect-starter-project and run it internally there's no issue with the import statements. But if I run npm init to make my own project, copy over the dependencies to my package.json, run npm install, then run node ./main.js it throws on the first line.

Comment: can you post file code

Comment: and you should post minimum information about code also

Comment: Try using require rather than import. Based on the package.json file it seems that repository uses typescript, which is then transpiled to js and run inside of a browser where as your script is being run through node as just plain javascript. The difference being that es6 style imports are probably converted at some point.

Here's a decent thing you could read: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c